# awk to count of occurrences then split into two file

Tags: awk

Would like to count number of occurences based on $2 field then split the input file into two output files ,
if the $2 field occurances more than 3 times then those lines re-dirceted into OpFile11.txt else re-directed into OpFile22.txt

Input.csv

```
Des1,Location,Decs2
aaa,a123,xxx
bbb,b789,yyy
xxx,a123,aaa
aaa,a123,xxx
bbb,b789,yyy
ccc,c567,zzz
xxx,a123,aaa
ddd,d456,ddd
```

OpFile11.txt

```
aaa,a123,xxx
xxx,a123,aaa
aaa,a123,xxx
xxx,a123,aaa
```

OpFile22.txt

```
bbb,b789,yyy
bbb,b789,yyy
ccc,c567,zzz
ddd,d456,ddd
```

Step#1 : Counting number of occurence:

```
awk -F, '{key=$2;++a[key]} END {for(i in a) print i","a[i]}' Input.csv 

d456,1
b789,2
c567,1
a123,4
```

Step#2 : Spliting the input file into two parts:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in a) { print $0 }' OccurGR3.csv Input.csv > OpFile11.txt
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} !($2 in a) { print $0 }' OccurGR3.csv Input.csv > OpFile22.txt
```

where OccurGR3.csv

```
a123,4
```

Please suggest to avoid  three steps , looking for your suggestions !!!

Comment: what are you doing in step 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR { cnt[$2]++; next }
{ print > ( "OpFile" (cnt[$2]<3?22:11) ".txt" ) }
' Input.csv Input.csv
```

Comment: Wow EdMorton , Rocking as usual , Thanks a ton , I have accepted the answer and up-voted  !!!